# Cloud deploying a function of inbuilt functions with TextCases (neural network)

Tags: cloud-deploy

Is it possible to use `TextCases` (a in-built function) in cloud-deploy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...? What you like to supply as an input and what would you like to get as a result and why does the fact that you'll cloud deploy this matter?